# addressing jsps from jsp submit button changes the request URL

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

i am devloping a Spring Mvc application where i am making a basic login app when i send it to controller it goes fine and display the error page when login fails now when i hit the relogin button which is a submit button i have to give the path as /jsps/Logn.jsp as my jsp are in jsps folder again submitting the request it creates a url as /jsps/Login.do and this does not reach to my controller as it is mapped to /Login.do which goes fine for the first time

can anyone please me with this?

This is my login page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Login.do">
        Enter Login Details <br> 
        UserName::  <input type="text" name = "username"><br>
        Password::  <input type="password" name = "password"><br>
        <input type= "submit" value = "Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my error page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Error While logging in please try again <br>`enter code here`
<form action = "jsps/Login.jsp">
<input type = "submit" value  = "try again">
</form>

</html>
```

this is my controller code

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Login.do")
public class LoginController {



    @RequestMapping("/Login.do")
    public ModelAndView checkLoginDetails(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response){


        if(request.getParameter("username") != null && request.getParameter("password") != null){

        if(request.getParameter("username").equalsIgnoreCase("admin") && request.getParameter("password").equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){
            return new ModelAndView("Home" );
        }else{
            return new ModelAndView("Error" );
        }
        }else{
            return new ModelAndView("Error" );
        }

    }

}
```

URL Displayed are

when i first hit the login button the url is

localhost/SpringLoginExample/Login.do?username=&password=

when i hit try again buton on the error page it takes me back to login page then if i hit the login button the url generated is

localhost/SpringLoginExample/jsps/Login.do?username=&password=

Comment: Where is your code? What's the URL displayed in the address bar of the page displaying the relogin button?

Comment: What ViewResolver are you using? UrlBasedViewResolver? How are they configured? Are you using only JSPs, or other view technology such as Tiles?

Comment: i am using internalresourceviewresolver and i am only using jsps not other view tech

Comment: The action in your form is `jsps/Login.jsp`, so obviously, submitting the form goes to this URL. You should never send a request to a view directly. Always go to a controller first. The action in your form should be to Login.do. And you shouldn't even have a form, but a simple link.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML configuration should look like this, if your jsps are located in war/jsps

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsps/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

You should avoid double annotation in your controller. There is a global annotation at class level, where all your @RequestMapping methods are mapped to, but you also use another method level mapping, which is redundant, as it is for the same url. I'd also differentiate between login checks and pure loading of the login page, by 2 different urls (as shown below) or by using a GET request for page display and a POST for credentials check.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping("/Login")
    public String loginPage(){
        return "Login"; // display a page that is named Login.jsp in your jsps folder
    }

    @RequestMapping("/Check")
    public ModelAndView checkLoginDetails(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response){
    ...
    }
}
```

Now you can use `<form action = "/Check"> ...` to send a validation request to your controller. Not only from your Login page, but from every other page also. Though: Your way of doing a relogin is not the usual way to provide another possibility for a user to login, after a failed login.

I'd recommend 4 possibilities:

1. Just provide a plain html link back to the login page `<a href="/Login"> try again </a>`
2. Also provide username and password field in your error page and use the same "action" as in the original login page `<form action = "/Check">`
3. The best solution with plain Spring MVC would be to look into [Form Validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) provided by Spring, which would allow you to check your form attributes and return to the page before with a custom error message for each field (here username or password)
4. In case of logins you do not have to reinvent the wheel. Take a look into [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) that is best suited for adding security/logins to your Spring web application

Answer (score 0):

You should first see the xml configuration. Check for the following code in it.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsps/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

if still it does not work let me know I'll give a different solution to deal with this.